# Docker private registry token authentication failed with status: 400 Bad Request

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Following is my **docker-compose.yml** file where I have hosted my private docker registry with domain **registry.MY-DOMAIN.com**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  registry:
    image: registry:latest
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET: b8f62d22-9a3f-4c73-bf5e-e0864b400bc8          

      #S3 bucket as docker storage
      REGISTRY_STORAGE: s3
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY: XXXXXXXXX
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY: XXXXXXXXX
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION: us-east-1
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET: docker-registry

      #Docker token based authentication
      REGISTRY_AUTH: token
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM: "https://api.MY-DOMAIN.com/api/developer-auth/login"
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE: Authentication
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER: "Let's Encrypt"
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_AUTOREDIRECT: false

      #Letsencrupt certificate
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE: "/certs/live/registry.MY-DOMAIN.com/fullchain.pem"
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: "/certs/live/registry.MY-DOMAIN.com/fullchain.pem"
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: "/certs/live/registry.MY-DOMAIN.com/privkey.pem"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

    restart: always

    volumes:
      - "/etc/letsencrypt:/certs"
```

When I try to login to my API server it return the following error

```
❯ docker login registry.MY-DOMAIN.com

Username: Elda86@yahoo.com

Password:

Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://api.MY-DOMAIN.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request
```

I don't have **username** field in my NodeJS API talking to the MongoDB database. Can I pass the email instead of **username**?

I want to do Docker Registry Token Authentication with my custom API that is written in NodeJS (ExpressJS) application. So that users can log in as "docker login registry.mydomain.com" and push the image once authenticated. I want the same experience as that of DockerHub. I am setting up a similar to DockerHub for my product. It acts as a docker store.

May I know how can I fix the issue?

Comment: What does NodeJS and MongoDB have to do with the Docker Registry?

Comment: @BMitch I want to do Docker Registry Token Authentication with my custom API that is written in NodeJS (ExpressJS) application. So that users can log in as "docker login registry.mydomain.com" and push the image once authenticated. 

I want the same experience as that of DockerHub. I am setting up a similar to DockerHub for my product. It acts as a docker store.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your token auth service is not correctly implemented.

You should implement it according to the specification.

See

- [Token Authentication Specification](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/)
- [Token Authentication Implementation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/jwt/)
- [Token Scope Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/scope/)
- [OAuth2 Token Authentication](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/oauth/)

for more information.

I would also recommend to look into actual existing implementations.

Such as:

- https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth
- https://github.com/adigunhammedolalekan/registry-auth
- https://github.com/twosigma/docker-repo-auth-demo